# System date generation in a text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I have a text box for DATE, When I click on the page where this "date" text box is written, I want the system date to be auto generated.

This is my Div and the input type:

```
<div id="date_text_label"> Date </div>

<input type="text" style=" padding: 3px 0;" id="date" />
```

I have tried this and it works. But the problem is it is not getting saved in the database. It gets saved as 00-00-0000:

```
<body onload="addDate();">
    <div id="date_text_label"> Date </div>
    <input type="text" style=" padding: 3px 0;" id="date" READONLY/><br/>
</body>
```

This is the javascript code:

```
function addDate(){
    date = new Date();             
    var month = date.getMonth()+1;
    var day = date.getDate();
    var year = date.getFullYear();

    if (document.getElementById('date').value == ''){
        document.getElementById('date').value = day + '-' + month + '-' + year;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Loktar asking others first, try later when no-one answers questions that are very simple after a small bit of research! :-/

Comment: <body onload="addDate();">
          <div id="date_text_label"> Date </div>
          <input type="text" style=" padding: 3px 0;" id="date" READONLY/><br/>
          </body>

I have tried this and it works. But the problem is it is not getting saved in the database. It gets saved as 00-00-0000

//This is the js code

function addDate(){
date = new Date();             
var month = date.getMonth()+1;
var day = date.getDate();
var year = date.getFullYear();

if (document.getElementById('date').value == ''){
document.getElementById('date').value = day + '-' + month + '-' + year;
}
}

Comment: @user1425994 - Edit your question to include this code.

Comment: How does your table structure where you want to save this looks like? And what is the code that tries to insert this to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it's being stored in your database in the incorrect format is that your date parser probably doesnt understand the formatting of your date string. You will either need to specify it like "MM-dd-YYYY" or store the date in your database as a string(not the best idea if you want to do queries against it)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/sWyCn/

```
​$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#date_text_label').click(function() {
    $('#date').val(new Date());
    });        
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple, you should be able to work it out for yourself from W3Schools.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp